# How to get clicked component of Layout in Vaadin?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have one [VerticalLayout](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/VerticalLayout.html) and I added 5 [Image](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Image.html) components to it. I would like to know which image component was clicked by user ? Here is my code

```
    myVerticalLayout.addLayoutClickListener(new LayoutClickListener() {

        public void layoutClick(final LayoutClickEvent event) {
            System.out.println(event.getSource().getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
    });
```

But I always get only **VerticalLayout** instead of user clicked image component. I have no idea how to do it ? Can sombody give me some suggesstions ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Now I found the answer. I use `event.getClickedComponent()` to get it. But if user was clicked on empty space of **Layout** , this method will return **null**.